# How to know if hard drive supports Sata3 (6Gb/s)

Tags: 11.10, sata

What tool can I use to see if a hard drive supports Sata3 (6Gb/s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SATA 3 interface has been out since 2009 so it is likely most new hard drives support it.

I would use Disk Utility to inspect the drive and it will tell you what model it is then you can get the specs from the manufacturers website.

The issue will be with the motherboard - if it is a older model the chipset may not support the transfer rate.

[image: Disk Utility]

There is a good article for reference of the SATA standard on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_ATA).

Comment: Actually Disk Utility does not say anywhere what Sata is supported in the drive (would be cool though). That is why I put the hdparm command.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda`.

Forgot that **hdparm** had the option to see Sata1, Sata2, Sata3, NQC and more. But a gui tool would be much better.

This would show what technologies the drive supports (assuming it is the sda): `sudo hdparm -I /dev/sda| grep '*'`

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in /dev/sd?; do
   echo $i; sudo hdparm -I $i|egrep 'Model|SATA.R'
done
```

will do the trick.

Really old drives that don't do SATA at all will only list a Model.

```
/dev/sda
    Model Number:       WDC WD5000AAKX-001CA0
    Transport:          Serial, SATA 1.0a, SATA II Extensions, SATA Rev 2.5, SATA Rev 2.6, SATA Rev 3.0
```

SATA Rev 3.0 is what you want.